# SQL Server Analysis Services Third Party Algorithms

Tags: sql-server, ssas

I have recently been trying the SQL Server Analysis Services for SQL Server 2005. I have built a couple of projects and did a bit of analysis but I was wondering if anyone knows of third party data mining libraries that can be plugged in SQL Server. I would like to compare the performance of the Microsoft algorithms with those from other libraries.

Comment: What are you looking for exactly? An alternate tool to compare with SSAS that can data mine from MsSQL databases?

Comment: Yes I would like to work within mssql but use other libraries if possible just for comparison.